# Why the value of signed char is greater than the unsigned int

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    unsigned int i = 23;
    signed char c = -23;
    if (i<c)
       puts("TRUE");

    return 0;
}
```

Why the output of the following program is TRUE, even though I have used signed char which can store from -128 to 127.

Comment: Default integer promotions.  Both variables are converted to `unsigned int`, and `-23` as an `unsigned int` is a lot bigger than `23`.  Print the values to see that. See C11 [§6.3.1.1 Conversions / Arithmetic operands / Booleans, characters and integers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) and [§6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8).

Comment: Note, this is why its dangerous to compare types with different signs. It's strongly advised to compile with the `-Wextra` flag, both gcc and clang generate a warning when such a comparison is discovered. gcc's is _warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'unsigned int' and 'signed char' [-Wsign-compare]_, clang's is similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `i < c` comparison has operands of two different types, so the operand with the smaller type (lower rank) is converted to the type of the other. In this case, as `-23` cannot be represented as an `unsigned int`, and following the "usual arithmetic conversions," it will end up with a value considerably greater than `+23` (actually, `UINT_MAX + 1 - 23`), according to Paragraph #2 in the following excerpt from [this (Draft) C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1    When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
> 2    Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
> repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type.
> 3    Otherwise, the new type is signed and the
> value cannot be represented in it; either the result is
> implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is
> raised.

You can see this conversion in action by assigning `c` to a separate `unsigned int` and printing its value, as in the following code. Assuming a 32-bit `unsigned int`, you will likely see a value of `4294967273` (which is, indeed, greater than `23`).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 23;
    signed char c = -23;
    unsigned int uc = c; // Add a diagnostic line ...
    printf("%u\n", uc);  // ... and show the value being used in the comparison
    if (i < c) {
        printf("TRUE");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Note: The relative *size* of the two variables (`i` and `c`) here is something of a red herring; even if you declare `c` as `signed int c = -23;`, you will still get the same result, due to the [Usual Arithmetic Conversions](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8) (link courtesy of Jonathan Leffler's comment) – note that a `signed int` cannot represent *all possible* values of an `unsigned int`, so the very last of the 'hollow' bullets will come into play.

Answer (score 4):

In order to make the comparison, the smallest variable (char, 8 bit) must be promoted to the size **and signedness** of the larger one (integer, 32 bit). But in so doing, -23 becomes 4294967273. Which is much more than 23.

If you compare `c` with a *signed* integer, the sign promotion causes no change and the test behaves as expected.